# Laravel 5.0: Form::select() called twice Eloquent Accessor by select name

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, accessor

**Blade template:**

```php
{!! Form::model($category) !!}

    {!! Form::select('drinks_id', [...full list...]) !!}

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

`'drinks_id'` called by **Eloquent Accessor:**

```php
public function getDrinksIdAttribute()
{
    var_dump('get');
    return 123;
}
```

When `Form::select('drinks_id')` execute, `getDrinksIdAttribute()` called twice and print `string(3) "get" string(3) "get"` from `var_dump()`.

If I write this:

```php
{!! Form::model($category) !!}

    {!! var_dump($category->drinks_id) !!}

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

it called `getDrinksIdAttribute()` once.

This is `Form::select()` bug, or I do something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FormBuilder` use `object_get()` helper function for get value from model:

```php
/**
 * Get the model value that should be assigned to the field.
 *
 * @param  string  $name
 * @return string
 */
protected function getModelValueAttribute($name)
{
    if (is_object($this->model))
    {
        return object_get($this->model, $this->transformKey($name));
    }
    elseif (is_array($this->model))
    {
        return array_get($this->model, $this->transformKey($name));
    }
}
```

`object_get()` called Eloquent Accessor twice:

[image: object_get() helper function code]

---

**The solution:**

```php
{!! Form::model($category) !!}

    {!! Form::select('drinks_id', [...full list...], $category->drinks_id) !!}

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

---